# Home component is repeating in the browser

Tags: vuejs2

I have a vue project with some nested components. Right now I have a main 'app-home' component with other components imported into it. The main app component, however displays 2 versions of 'app-home'. None of the other nested components are being repeated inside the home component.

This is a pretty basic project so far as I am just building out the structure right now. I'm not repeating the tags in the app component.

app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-home></app-home>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AppHome from './components/AppHome.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      'app-home': AppHome
    }
  }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

apphome.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="page-container">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
    <app-nav></app-nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AppToolbar from './AppToolbar.vue'
  import AppNav from './AppNav.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      'app-toolbar': AppToolbar,
      'app-nav': AppNav
    },
    title: 'githubrater',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'app home works'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

For some reason the entire app-home component is displayed twice when I view my browser. Is there anything I am doing in App.vue that would cause this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you also share your _router.js_ (or wherever you defined `router-view` or `Router`)? Perhaps you also set the router to load the `AppHome` component..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rendered first time from your app-home component declaration.

```
<app-home></app-home>
```

And second time as :

You have also added router-view and hence it will render your app-home component within your router-view element as most probably you would have declared app-home on route '/'. Hence remove app-home component declaration and let router render your app-home component.